# Word that means "in the process of being repaired"?

Tags: word-request

Is the correct word *repairing*? Example sentence:

> He hauled his iPad from inside his desk, a temporary replacement for his __ iPhone, and held it before my eyes. "Check this out."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a word that can be used for this. you could say it a few different ways though.

1. A temporary replacement for his **broken** iPhone.
2. A temporary replacement **until** his iPhone **is fixed**.
3. A temporary replacement for his iPhone

Answer (score 1):

The bridge is **under repair**.

The elevator is **under repair**.

But to say that about a phone sounds weird: (My iPhone is under repair.)